# cout of string doesn't show anything

Tags: c++, string

The cout of `encrypted` string doesn't show anything and sometimes the program crashes. And when i do `cout << encrypted[i]` in for loop , i got the correct result. Also if i do a for loop to read string char by char `for(char c:encrypted)` , `cout << c << endl;` => it doesn't work also and got garbage.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    string key = "XZNLWEBGJHQDYVTKFUOMPCIASRxznlwebgjhqdyvtkfuompciasr";
    string encrypted;
    string decrypted;
    string message;
    int pos{};
    cout << "enter the message" << endl;
    getline(cin,message);


    //encrypting
    for (size_t i{} ;i<message.length();i++)
        {   
            if (alphabet.find(message[i]) != string::npos)
            {pos = alphabet.find(message[i]);        

            encrypted[i] = key[pos];                    

            }else
             {encrypted[i]=message[i];
                cout << encrypted[i];
             }
        }

    cout << "the encrypted message is: "<< encrypted << endl;
```

Comment: `encrypted` is initialised as an empty string.   `encrypted[i] = key[pos]` does not change that - in fact it gives undefined behaviour.   Lack of output is only one possible symptom - your code may be writing to random memory.   Either append characters needed to `encrypted`, or resize the string as needed BEFORE doing such assignments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After `string encrypted;` `encrypted` is default-initialized as empty `std::string` which contains no elements. Then any access to non-existent elements like `encrypted[i]` leads to UB.

You can use `push_back` (or `operator+=`) instead.

```
//encrypting
for (size_t i{}; i<message.length(); i++)
{   
    if (alphabet.find(message[i]) != string::npos)
    {
        pos = alphabet.find(message[i]);        
        encrypted.push_back(key[pos]);                    
    } 
    else
    {
        encrypted.push_back(message[i]);    
        cout << encrypted[i];
    }
}
```

Or initialize `encrypted` with `message.length()` elements in advance.

```
getline(cin,message);
string encrypted(message.length(), '\0'); // initialize encrypted as containing message.length() elements with value '\0'

//encrypting
for (size_t i{}; i<message.length(); i++)
{
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

```
Default constructor. Constructs empty string (zero size and unspecified capacity)
```